# mysql : Select from tab1 where exists in tab2. tab2 name is concat(tab1.id + '_details)

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation, exists

Can you guys help me for this :

I have these tables

products :

```
ID |   udate    | desc
-------------------------
1  | 2016-03-23| item a    
2  | 2016-03-24| item b
```

**1**_details :

```
enter_date | qty | enable | para2 ...
-------------------------------------------
 2016-02-23|  5  |    1   | ... | ...
```

**2**_details :

```
enter_date | qty | enable | para2 ...
-------------------------------------------
 2016-02-24|  6  |   0    | ... | ...
```

I would like to :

```
Select all from products where

Exists (Select From products.id+'details' Where enable - '1')
```

My problem is to concatenate the name of the table in the Exists.

The result should be :
1 | 2016-03-23| item a

Comment: How did you end up with two details tables. Oops. Fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Strawberry. Well that configuration is just an exemple to show a situation where I wanna dynamically create a table name. I was wondering if it was possible and if yes how.

Comment: You would never want to do this. To do so would typically be a symptom of poor design.

Comment: ok thanks. Just to precise that I don't want to do this I was just wondering if it was possible to concatenate a table name while parsing a first table.